# Swift: UITableView Cell Disappears When Using UIView.animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animatewithduration

I am programmatically adding a UITableView as a subview of a view that uses UIView.animateWithDuration to expand the view when a button is clicked from a single point to a full window. Basically, a box that starts as a point and expands to full size with an animation.  I am having difficulties getting the table to populate with cells.  At first, a cell was being created, but would disappear after quickly after the animation completed, after playing around with it, I have gotten the cell to remain after the animation is complete, but now the cell disappears when I tap on it.  I don't understand what is going on here. Can someone please help?

Here is my code. Note, I have removed what I believe to be irrelevant to this problem to make the code easier to read.

```
class PokerLogSelectionView: UIViewController {

    let logSelectionTableViewController = LogSelectionTableViewController()
    let logSelectionTableView = UITableView()

    // Irrelevant class variables removed

    init(btn : PokerLogSelectionButton){
        // Irrelevant view initialization code removed

        // Display the subviews
        self.displayLogListScrollView()
    }

    func displayLogListScrollView() {

        // Frame is set to (0,0,0,0)
        let frame = CGRect(x: self.subviewClosed, y: self.subviewClosed, width: self.subviewClosed, height: self.subviewClosed)

        logSelectionTableView.delegate = self.logSelectionTableViewController
        logSelectionTableView.dataSource = self.logSelectionTableViewController

        // Set the frame of the table view
        logSelectionTableView.frame = frame

        // Give it rounded edges
        logSelectionTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        // Remove the cell divider lines
        logSelectionTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

        logSelectionTableView.backgroundColor = logSelectionViewContentScrollViewColor

        self.view.addSubview(logSelectionTableView)

        //self.logSelectionTableView.reloadData()

        //self.addChildViewController(logSelectionTableViewController)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // Create animation
        let timeInterval : NSTimeInterval = 0.5
        let delay : NSTimeInterval = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(timeInterval, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            // Irrelevant code removed

            // Set the size and position of the view and subviews after the animation is complete
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.frameXopen, y: self.frameYopen, width: self.frameWopen, height: self.frameHopen)
            self.logSelectionTableView.frame = CGRect(x: self.subviewXopen, y: self.svYopen, width: self.subviewWopen, height: self.svHopen)


            }, completion: { finished in
                self.addChildViewController(self.logSelectionTableViewController)
        })
    }
}

class LogSelectionTableViewController : UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerClass(LogSelectionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "logCell")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pokerLibrary.logNames.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Selected row: \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell : LogSelectionCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("logCell") as? LogSelectionCell {

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


            cell.textLabel!.text = pokerLibrary.logNames[indexPath.row].name

            return cell
        }
        fatalError("Could not dequeue cell of type 'LogSelectionCell'")
    }

}
```

Note: I can see the tableview after the animation is complete. The color is different than the view in the background view and the tableview does not disappear, just the cell.  I expect there to be 1 cell, and I have printed out the number of rows in section 0 and it always returns 1.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

Here is a screenshot of the view hierarchy before the cell disappears.
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the view hierarchy after I tap the cell and it disappears.
[image]

I overrode the touchesBegan method in my custom cell and did not call its superclass method. This stopped the cell from disappearing when I tap it, but it still disappears when I scroll the tableView.

Comment: Please provide some more info. Use the View inspector in Xcode while running to tell us whether the cells are gone or just not visible, as well as any properties of the tableview.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning swift and xcode. The cell appears in the view hierarchy before I tap on it, once I tap on it, it disappears, so I am assuming that the cell is gone. Is there another way to tell?  The tableview remains just as it is set up in the code above.

Comment: I should note that I have no idea what code is even being called when I tap the cell.  As you can see in the code above, I put a print statement in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, but this never prints to the console when I tap the cell.

Comment: Cells don't just disappear unless the dataSource methods change. TableView might be disappearing? have you set a background colour or added a footer view to the tableview to test it is there. Taking screenshots of the view inspector may help too. (pre/post)

Comment: I do have a background color set for the tableview, and it remains as it should before and after.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by view inspector.

Comment: Click the button indicated here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ut5vz19km7wgs2k/Untitled.png?dl=0